# Why isn't string resetting inside the loop?

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop

I'm making a small desk cost program for a class. I wanted to include a loop into it. But every time I get to the end of the program and loop it back to the beginning, it skips the part where I ask for the customers name and leaves it blank. Any idea how to fix it?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>            // needed for Cin and Cout
#include <string>              // needed for the String class
#include <math.h>              // math functions
#include <stdlib.h>             
using namespace std;

#define  baseCost  200.00
#define  drawerPrice 30.00

int main(void)
{
    while(true)
    {
        string cname;
        char ch;

        cout << "What is your name?\n";
        getline(cin, cname);

        cout << cname;

        cout << "\nWould you like to do another? (y/n)\n";
        cin >> ch;

        if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
            continue;
        else
            exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have a while loop around main? Does this even compile? >.<

Comment: Since you've identified that the problem is with the loop & string, can you reduce the code to just that? That makes it a lot easier for everyone. (P.S: `while (true) int main() { ...` what?)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your copy-paste seems to be broken.

Comment: There's a simplified version of it. (Sorry for the 'while' placement error)

Comment: I hope the actual code you give the students isn't like that :-(

The reason its failing is you haven't red the rest of the line from cin after the y/n, so the getline gets the newline and nothing else.

Comment: I'm not a teacher. I'm trying to learn this stuff on my own because our teacher sucks. Tom Tanner can you show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to call cin.ignore() after your prompt for exit. When you use cin to get the 'ch' variable, a newline character is still stored in the input buffer. Call cin.ignore(), to ignore that character.

If you don't, you'll notice that the program prints a newline as the name on the second loop.

You could also make the 'ch' variable a string like 'cname' and use getline instead of cin. Then you wouldn't have to issue the cin.ignore() call.

```
#include <iostream>            // needed for Cin and Cout
#include <string>              // needed for the String class
#include <math.h>              // math functions
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#define  baseCost  200.00
#define  drawerPrice 30.00

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        string cname;
        char ch;

        cout << "What is your name?\n";
        getline(cin, cname);

        cout << cname;

        cout << "\nWould you like to do another? (y/n)\n";
        cin >> ch;

        // Slightly cleaner
        if (ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y')
            exit(1);

        cin.ignore();

        /*
        if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
            continue;
        else
            exit(1);
        */
    }

    return 0;
}
```